# Yfinance and lightweight charts Failed download

Tags: python, yfinance, lightweight-charts

I have followed the tutorial on github https://github.com/louisnw01/lightweight-charts-python but I always have the same error. this is my code and result

```
import datetime as dt
from time import sleep
from lightweight_charts import Chart
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf

ticker = yf.Ticker('MSFT')
hist = ticker.history(period="max")
stocks = ['TSLA', 'MSFT', 'NIO', 'AAPL', 'AMD', 'ADBE', 'ALGN', 'AMZN',
      'AMGN', 'AEP', 'ADI', 'ANSS', 'AMAT', 'ASML', 'TEAM', 'ADSK']


data = yf.download("stocks", start="2023-01-01", end="2023-11-15", interval = "3mo")
                   

df1 = pd.read_csv('/Users/cilincilin/lightweight_chart/ohlc.csv')


df2 = pd.read_csv('/Users/cilincilin/lightweight_chart/ticks.csv')
print(df2)


chart.set(df1)

chart.show()

for i, tick in df2.iterrows():
    chart.update_from_tick(tick)
        
    sleep(0.03)
chart.show(block=True)
```

======================================================================

ERROR

```
weight_chart/main.py
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed

1 Failed download:
['STOCKS']: Exception('%ticker%: No timezone found, symbol may be delisted')
  Unnamed: 0                              time   price
0              0  2023-05-04 15:15:17.630544+00:00  162.56
1              1  2023-05-04 15:15:17.695618+00:00  162.56
2              2  2023-05-04 15:15:17.788727+00:00  162.56
3              3  2023-05-04 15:15:18.655228+00:00  162.54
4              4  2023-05-04 15:15:18.789878+00:00  162.54
...          ...                               ...     ...
2460        2460  2023-05-04 15:21:10.339107+00:00  162.08
2461        2461  2023-05-04 15:21:10.564931+00:00  162.08
2462        2462  2023-05-04 15:21:10.578956+00:00  162.08
```

I'm trying to get it to work I hope you can find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

use as `data = yf.download(stocks, start="2023-01-01", end="2023-11-15", interval = "3mo")`
stocks is not a string its a list of stocks